# Scania’s Air Pressure System's Failures

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, eda

I am working on a Data set called Scania’s Air Pressure System's Failures.

The dataframe has columns with missing values.

How do I replace the zero with the mean?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dataframe is `df`, if one wants to change all the zeros throughout every column, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) like this

```
df = df.replace(0, df.mean())
```

If one wants to do it for just one column (`column_name`), one can use [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) as follows

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].replace(0, df['column_name'].mean())
```

If one has `NaN`, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as follows

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

If the `NaN` are just in the column `column_name`, one can use [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) as follows

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].fillna(df['column_name'].mean())
```